# Filter on nested object in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query in LINQ to return a policy object with a list of its policy risks, and within the policy risk a list of its transaction movements.

```
corePolicy = _db.Policies
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.BatchId)
    .Include(policy => policy.PolicyRisks.Select(policyRisks =>
        policyRisks.TransactionMovements))
    .Include(policy => policy.PolicyRisks.Select(policyRisks =>
        policyRisks.PolicyRiskClaims.Select(prc =>
            prc.TransactionMovements)))
    .AsNoTracking()
    .First(p =>
        p.PolicyReference == policyFromStaging.PolicyReference &&
        p.PolicySourceSystemId == policyFromStaging.PolicySourceSystemId);
```

How do I apply a *.Where()* clause to the transaction movements, say `TransactionReference == 'ABC'`

Below is my data model

```
[Table("business.Policy")]
public class Policy
{
    [Required, StringLength(50)]
    public string PolicyReference { get; set; }

    public int PolicySourceSystemId { get; set; }
    public System PolicySourceSystem { get; set; }
}

[Table("business.PolicyRisk")]
public class PolicyRisk
{
    public ICollection<TransactionMovement> TransactionMovements { get; set; }
}

[Table("business.TransactionMovement")]
public class TransactionMovements
{
    public string TransactionReference { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us models of `Policy`, `PolicyRisks` and the transaction movement. Create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) This would be really helpful to understand what you want

Comment: Here add your, data model so one can help you to design efficient LINQ query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having Where statement in Include is not possible. You can have Any something like below:

```
corePolicy = _db.Policies
.OrderByDescending(p => p.BatchId)
.Include(policy => policy.PolicyRisks.Select(policyRisks =>
    policyRisks.TransactionMovements))
.Include(policy => policy.PolicyRisks.Select(policyRisks =>
    policyRisks.PolicyRiskClaims.Select(prc =>
        prc.TransactionMovements)))
.AsNoTracking()
.Where(p => p.PolicyRisks.Any(pr => pr.PolicyRiskClaims.Any(prc => prc.TransactionMovements.Any(tm => tm.TransactionReference == 'ABC'))))
.First(p =>
    p.PolicyReference == policyFromStaging.PolicyReference &&
    p.PolicySourceSystemId == policyFromStaging.PolicySourceSystemId);
```

This will include policies if any of the transaction reference is ABC (on its child collections). So, again you have to have a  looping mechanism in c# side to get the policy which have this TransactionReference.

If you want to avoid having loop, then I would suggest writing your linq from other end meaning, start from TransactionMovement and go back to Policy.

You can have WHERE clause in Include filter with some third party library as mentioned [here](https://entityframework.net/include-with-where-clause).

Comment: Unfortunately I get the following error when trying the above `The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.`